# How can I scp a file with a colon in the file name?

Tags: bash, escaping, scp

I'm trying to copy a file using `scp` in `bash` with a colon (`:`) character in the source filename. The obfuscated version of my command I'm using is:

```
scp file\:\ name.mp4 user@host:"/path/to/dest"
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname Portal 2: Name or service not known
```

I know I could just rename the file and remove the `:`, but I'd like to know if it's possible to escape the colon.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Not quite a `bash` escaping problem, it's `scp` treating `x:` as a [user@]host prefix, try:

```
scp ./file:\ name.mp4 user@host:"/path/to/dest"
```

Using relative (e.g. `./`) or fully qualified paths (`/path/to/source`) prevents this behaviour - the presence of `/` before a `:` causes OpenSSH to stop checking for a possible `host:` or `user@host:` prefix).

OpenSSH's `scp` only special-cases filenames that *start* with a colon allowing those to work without problems, it has no support for escaping a `:` in the normal sense, and has no other notion of valid hostnames so almost any filename with a `:` can cause this (or equivalent IPv6 behaviour if `[` `]` are found before `:`).

This can also affect other programs, e.g. `rsync`, the same workaround applies there.

(Due to OpenSSH's simplistic parsing of `[]` enclosed IPv6 addresses, you can successfully `scp` files containing `:` which start with `[`, or contain `@[` before the `:` and do not contain `]:` , but that's not generally useful ;-)

---

(**The below text was written** when the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14718720/1) was *How do I escape a colon in bash?* It applies to that situation, but not to `scp` as no amount of shell escaping will help there.)

To answer the question about *how* to escape `:`, you don't need to, but "`\:`" works. Places that a `:` is used:

1. the null command `:`, no need to escape, though you can, just like `\e\c\h\o foo` it has no effect on the command ("no effect" is not completely true, if you escape one or more characters it will prevent an alias being matched, and you *can* alias `:`)
2. `PATH` (and others, `CDPATH`, `MAILPATH`) escaping the values has no useful effect (I have been unable to run a program in my PATH from a directory containing a `:`, which is a little unexpected)
3. parameter expansion `${name:-x}` and more, `name` must be `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so no need to escape variables names, and since there's no ambiguity, no need to escape subsequent `:` in the other variations of parameter expansion
4. `? :` trinary operates only on variables and numbers, no need to escape
5. `==` and `=~` with classes in the pattern like `[[:digit:]]`, you can escape with `\:` but I'm at a loss as to how that might ever be useful...
6. within command or function names, no need to escape, `\:` has no useful effect

(Note that the null command is just `:`, you can have a command or function named like "`:foo`" and it can be invoked without escaping, in this respect it's different to `#` where a command named `#foo` would need to be escaped.)

Comment: Same problem affects `rsync`. Fortunately, same solution -- prefixing the filename(s) with `./` -- helps there too.

Comment: trinary :) or ternary?

Answer (score 2):

I try using fully qualified paths as @mr.spuratic answer but not work and in my situation, I have to use absolute paths, this is my solution:

```
scp `hostname`:/root/this/is/test/file.txt user@host:"/path/to/dest"
```