# scp "connection lost" when transferring files from Mac to ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I have created a EC2 instance and is trying to launch a flask api (with tensorflow) on it.

I am currently trying to transfer files over from my Mac to the EC2 instance, but keep getting the following error...

```
Connection closed by 100.26.246.133 port 22
lost connection
```

the scp command I am using is as follows.

```
scp -i /Users/joelleo/Desktop/Work/ICC:Computing/Projects:Events/SCSE/2021/others/ec2-no-restrictions.pem -r /Users/joelleo/Desktop/Work/ICC:Computing/Projects:Events/SCSE/2021/application/ ec2-100-26-246-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/app/
```

I have doubled check all the file paths and it is correct. also I have managed to successfully ssh into the ec2 instance and also managed to use scp in the past before

ssh into ec2 instance..

```
(base) joelleo@Joels-MacBook-Air others % ssh -i "ec2-no-restrictions.pem" ubuntu@ec2-100-26-246-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Wed Jan  6 16:44:00 UTC 2021

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           112
  Usage of /:   23.8% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 1%                IP address for eth0: 172.31.54.61
  Swap usage:   0%


51 packages can be updated.
33 updates are security updates.

New release '20.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Wed Jan  6 16:23:51 2021 from 115.66.136.180
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-61:~$
```

---

I have also checked that I am opening the correct ports in ec2 instance.

inbound rules..
[image]

outbound rules..
[image]

I read online that `scp` works using `ssh`.. can someone help as to why I am unable to connect using scp now?

thks!

Comment: Those colons in the filepaths in the `scp` command [make me uncomfy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718778/2052575).  This looks like some kind of connection problem though.  You may try using `scp` with the `-v` flag for more verbose output, which might lend some more clues.

Comment: Also, there is a problem with your SCP command, If you replace `:(colon) with _(underscore)` your command should be like this `scp -i /Users/joelleo/Desktop/Work/ICC_Computing/Projects_Events/SCSE/2021/others/ec2-no-restrictions.pem -r /Users/joelleo/Desktop/Work/ICC_Computing/Projects_Events/SCSE/2021/application/ ubuntu@ec2-100-26-246-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/app/`

**Explain**
`scp -i <.pem_file_location> -r <source_folder> <remote_host_user>:<remote_host_ip>`

Comment: Hey, @Red have your problem gets solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, some network problem between ec2 and the scp client. Perform below steps

1. Change internet connection and try again.
2. Cross check ec2 security group on AWS.
3. Perform `scp -v` verbose mode to identify why it is failing.